# How to change button repeatedly when tapped?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button

Using Swift, how do I make a:

1. Button with words "start", that changes to "pause" and vice versa when tapped? Not just once, but can be done infinitely? (e.g. in a stopwatch app)
2. Custom image button that changes between 2 image when tapped, that can also be done (tapped & change) infinitely?

Comment: Edit your post and show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I'm just randomly playing around with buttons.. nothing interesting to show! Yet! Haha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a Bool variable

```
var isPlaying:Bool = false
```

**Step 2:** Connect your button with this IBAction method:

```
@IBAction func btnStartStop(sender: UIButton) {
    if isPlaying{

        isPlaying = false
        sender.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setImage(pauseImage, forState: .Normal)
        //Pause Stopwatch
    }
    else{

        isPlaying = true
        sender.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setImage(playImage, forState: .Normal)
      //Play Stopwatch
    }
  }
```

Comment: Per my comment below, you shouldn't use the button title as your state test: what happens if the app is translated into another language, for example? Or the button title changes from *Play* to *Start*.  Use a `Bool` if necessary to store the state.

Comment: Then use Localised string on the place of Title String.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could listen to people who have years of experience as professional software developers!!

Comment: Thanks! It's simple and I understand! I just have 2 questions: 1) Is there no need to set a condition for the if statement in this case? Why can't it be done? e.g. if isPlaying = true
2) What does the "sender" means in this case? I was thinking inserting the button name would make more sense..
Please explain! Thank you so much!
@AshleyMills could you help too?

Comment: There's quite a lot to answer - you should think about creating a new question or updating your original to let other people help you.

Comment: @AllisterBah, 1). In Swift no need to check == true, if you write if isPlaying it will check weather it is true,otherwise false.
2.) Yes, you can choose any name you wants.

Comment: 2) But if I replace "sender" with my button name then there is the error: '(AnyObject) -> ()' does not have a member named 'setTitle'.

Comment: As Ashley suggested,Post new question.

Answer (score 4):

In your storyboard, set the **Default** state title to "Start" and the **Selected** state title to "Pause"

[image]

[image]

Or alternatively, if you're doing it in code:

```
startPauseButton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
startPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: .Selected)
```

In your `IBAction func`, toggle the `button.selected` property between `true` & `false`

```
@IBAction func toggleStopwatch(button:UIButton) {
    if button.selected {
        // Pause the stopwatch
    } else {
        // Start the stopwatch
    }
    button.selected = !button.selected
}
```

You can also set different images for different states: **Default**, **Highlighted**, **Selected**, **Disabled**

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
In the IBAction method, when I wrote button.selected there is an error:

'(AnyObject) -> ()' does not have a member named selected

What does it mean?
Also, I notice after writing "button", Xcode would prompt me to insert (sender: AnyObject), what does that mean?

Thanks for your time, I'm new to programming!

Comment: By default, Xcode creates an `IBAction` method with `AnyObject` as the parameter type. As you know you're connecting to a button, you can change the type to `UIButton` - either by changing the code, or by updating the *Type* to `UIButton` in the popup that appears when you connect in Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

In the @IBAction of the button (assuming you are using storyboards), you change the title or image of the button to what you want. You can also check for the title or image and perform an action based on what you have.

```
@IBAction func pressbutton(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.titleLabel?.text {
        case "Play":
        play()
        case "Pause":
        pause()
    default:
        other()
    }
    sender.titleLabel?.text = "Whatever you want"
}
```

Or with images (assuming you have an `images` array somewhere that stores the images, which you should):

```
@IBAction func pressbutton(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.imageView!.image! {
        case images[0]:
            play()
        case images[1]:
            pause()
    default:
        other()
    }
    sender.imageView?.image = UIImage(...)
}
```

Comment: It's very poor practice to use the button title as your state test: what happens if the app is translated into another language, for example?

Comment: @AshleyMills Then you can use the NSLocalisedString("Play") for your check, but the `selected` way is better imho

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
@IBAction func btnStopWatch(sender: UIButton) {
        if btnStopWatch.selected == true  {
            btnStopWatch.setTitle("stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btnStopWatch.setImage(stopImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btnStopWatch.selected = false
        } else {
            btnStopWatch.setTitle("start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btnStopWatch.setImage(startImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btnStopWatch.selected = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I tried to add .isSelected behind btnStopWatch but there's an error: '(AnyObject) -> ()' does not have a member named "isSelected".

What does this mean? I also notice that Xcode always prompts me to insert (sender: AnyObject) behind btnStopWatch. What does that mean?

I'm really new to programming but I hope I could learn something out of this! Thanks!

Comment: create this : @IBOutlet weak var btnStopWatch: UIButton!

Comment: There is another error now at the if btnStopWatch.isSelected level:
Could not find member 'isSelected'

Answer (score 0):

#### #1. Toggle a `UIButton` title

With Swift 3, `UIButton` has a method called [`setTitle(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle). `setTitle(_:for:)` has the following declaration:

```
func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)
```

> Sets the title to use for the specified state.

The following Playground code shows how to use `setTitle(_:for:)` in order to toggle the title of a button according to its state:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        // Set button's states
        button.setTitle("Start", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.selected)

        // set layout
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }

    /// trigger action when button is tapped
    func toggle(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        print("Button state: \(sender.isSelected)")
    }

}

let vc = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Preview your view controller in the Playground assistant editor using <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Assistant Editor</kbd> > <kbd>Show Assistant Editor</kbd>

---

#### #2. Toggle a `UIButton` image

`UIButton` has a method called [`setImage(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage). `setImage(_:for:)` has the following declaration:

```
func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState)
```

> Sets the image to use for the specified state.

The following Playground code shows how to use `setImage(_:for:)` in order to toggle the title of a button according to its state:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        // Set button's states
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "on.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "off.png"), for: UIControlState.selected)

        // set layout
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let heightConstraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        let widthConstraint = button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, heightConstraint, widthConstraint])
    }

    /// trigger action when button is tapped
    func toggle(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        print("Button state: \(sender.isSelected)")
    }

}

let vc = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Preview your view controller in the Playground assistant editor using <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Assistant Editor</kbd> > <kbd>Show Assistant Editor</kbd>